# Style my div structure as a tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Check this URL.
My divs are created dynamically in nested structure. I have to style this div to sports tournament structure. I don't know how to structure.

I want my structure like this.Now my code is working fine. Styling only the problem.

```
 [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKSwHAUdXcGZcwHTDmiv?p=preview
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you looking for a suitable plugin to render the graph for you, search for `angular organization chart` in google

Comment: @ Icycool  ya i serached no one is match my requirement. https://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=116&lang=en this is perfect. Too castly. if you know anything like that let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using org chart to achive my requirement.check below link

```
   [https://jsfiddle.net/dhaarani/adx0ad49/][1]
```

page load one structure is shown. click the structrue again one is created.

change the input box value. sibilling and child will be created. inputbox value mustbe lessthan 100.

and one more condition check the one row contain all the input box values total is lessthan 100 than only create sibilling and child otherwise nothing will be happen.